# What's the relative path of springdoc.swagger-ui.url?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

I'm trying to serve yml files on Swagger UI using springdoc, on the documentation [here](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-specyml) it says to specify the file like`springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/api-docs.yaml`, however, let's say I have those yml files in the main java folder, what value should `springdoc.swagger-ui.url` receive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your api-docs.yaml is located to in your static folder.

The standard spring configuration for static resources is:

- src/main/resrouces/static